# BlackBerry - ListFieldCallback deprecated

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, deprecated, listfield, rim-4.3

I am using 4.3.0 of the Blackberry JDE. 
I have created a ListField object and populated it by overriding ListFieldCallback.
It works but I am getting a compile warning that ListFieldCallback is deprecated.
What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [deprecated list for 4.3.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/deprecated-list.html). ListFieldCallback is not listed as a deprecated class.  And, it doesn't seem to be deprecated in newer releases either.  Are you sure it is ListFieldCallback that it is complaining about?

Comment: You were right it was something else that was deprecated. I was reading the compiler warning wrong.